# How add new context stacking in custom elements dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-element

I have a custom element. By clicking on it, a dropdown appears.

```
<component-dropdown></component-dropdown>
```

Is there a way to create a new overlay context (context stacking)? After all, the user may already have some kind of overlay context (context-stacking) and my dropdown will be cut off

Comment: No different than regular HTML. If you don't control the container, you can be *screwed* BUT at least a Web Component can check all parentNodes and behave accordingly. It is up to you to code for all (edge) cases.

Comment: @danny-365csi-engelman What can you think of in this case? Is it possible to move the web component or part of it to the end body?

Comment: see ``appendChild`` on MDN